# Select ordered list from Database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've received a table ordered in the following manner:

```
NR       | CATNAME
00       | Category 1
00.01    | Subcategory 1
00.01.01 | Subsubcategory 1
00.02    | Subcategory 2
01       | Category 2
01.01    | Subcategory 3
01.02    | Subcategory 4
01.02.01 | Subsubcategory
```

Is there a way to easily select all main categories or subcategories of a specific category (with excluding subsubcategories of this categorie) using SQL?
The problem is, the NR-Column is set as a VARCHAR so Math-Functions are probably not the best idea.

It's not my table and I can't change the Layout :/

Comment: What should be the expected output? And what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the tasks you describe, this is about the level in the tree. This you get by counting the dots:

```
-- All main categories:
select *
from mytable
where length(nr) - length(replace(nr,'.','')) = 0
order by nr;
```

```
NR       | CATNAME
---------+--------------
00       | Category 1
01       | Category 2
```

```
-- All direct subcategories of category '01':
select *
from mytable
where nr like '01%'
and length(nr) - length(replace(nr,'.','')) = 1
order by nr;
```

```
NR       | CATNAME
---------+--------------
01.01    | Subcategory 3
01.02    | Subcategory 4
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DKQYK10570

Comment: Never new SQL has so many functions. Thank you, worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

For all main categories you can use LENGTH() function.

```
select *
from   tbl
where  length(NR) = 2;
```

> ```
> NR | CATNAME   
> :- | :---------
> 00 | Category 1
> 01 | Category 2
> ```

For all components of a category you can use LIKE operator:

```
select *
from   tbl
where  NR like '00.01%';
```

> ```
> NR       | CATNAME         
> :------- | :---------------
> 00.01    | Subcategory 1   
> 00.01.01 | Subsubcategory 1
> ```

For all components of a category and their descendants you can use a combination of previous queries:

```
select tbl.*, t1.NR as filter
from   tbl
join   (select NR
        from   tbl
        where  length(NR) = 5) t1
on     tbl.NR like concat(t1.NR, '%');
```

> ```
> NR       | CATNAME          | filter
> :------- | :--------------- | :-----
> 00.01    | Subcategory 1    | 00.01 
> 00.01.01 | Subsubcategory 1 | 00.01 
> 00.02    | Subcategory 2    | 00.02 
> 01.01    | Subcategory 3    | 01.01 
> 01.02    | Subcategory 4    | 01.02 
> 01.02.01 | Subsubcategory   | 01.02
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d26b18b1835c6d8b6dd16cec1208c797)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL you can also use regular expressions to filter out categories and this is very convenient and allows to create semantically powerful queries (see below).

The following examples queries will be based on this data:

```
create table xxxx1(NR varchar, CATNAME varchar);
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('00', 'Category 1');
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('00.01', 'Subcategory 1');
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('00.01.01', 'Subsubcategory 1');
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('00.02', 'Subcategory 2');
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('01', 'Category 2');
insert into xxxx1(NR, CATNAME) values('01.01', 'Subcategory 3');
```

Examples:

All subcategories of Category 2:

```
select * from xxxx1 where NR REGEXP '^01.+';
+-------+---------------+
| NR    | CATNAME       |
+-------+---------------+
| 01.01 | Subcategory 3 |
+-------+---------------+
```

All subcategories of Category 1:

```
select * from xxxx1 where NR REGEXP '^00.+';
+----------+------------------+
| NR       | CATNAME          |
+----------+------------------+
| 00.01    | Subcategory 1    |
| 00.01.01 | Subsubcategory 1 |
| 00.02    | Subcategory 2    |
+----------+------------------+
```

All top categories:

```
select * from xxxx1 where NR REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9]$';
+------+------------+
| NR   | CATNAME    |
+------+------------+
| 00   | Category 1 |
| 01   | Category 2 |
+------+------------+
```

All subcategories at the second level:

```
mysql> select * from xxxx1 where NR REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]$';
+-------+---------------+
| NR    | CATNAME       |
+-------+---------------+
| 00.01 | Subcategory 1 |
| 00.02 | Subcategory 2 |
| 01.01 | Subcategory 3 |
+-------+---------------+
```

All subcategories at the third level:

```
mysql> select * from xxxx1 where NR REGEXP '^([0-9][0-9]\.?){3}$';
+----------+------------------+
| NR       | CATNAME          |
+----------+------------------+
| 00.01.01 | Subsubcategory 1 |
+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**categories+sub categories:**
SELECT ct1.id, ct1.name, ct2.id, ct2.name FROM categories_table ct1
  LEFT JOIN categories_table ct2
    ON ct2.parent_id = ct1.id
WHERE ct1.parent_id = CATNAMEORID
**categories+sub categories+sub sub categories:**
SELECT ct1.id, ct1.name, ct2.id, ct2.name, ct3.id, ct3.name FROM categories_table ct1
  LEFT JOIN categories_table ct2
    ON ct2.parent_id = ct1.id
  LEFT JOIN categories_table ct3
    ON ct3.parent_id = ct2.id
WHERE ct1.parent_id = CATNAMEORID